# Console terminal with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So far I managed to make this working fiddle. My problem now is that after I press enter to send the data to the server, i need to disable the edit on the current input and pass the focus to the next.

Also does anyone have any idea how do I make that text bliking thing in the project? https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/yNgQ1

**PS: you need to press enter to start the console**

```js
var terminal = $('#terminal');

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var stdin = $('.stdin').last().text();
    console.log(stdin);
    consoleInteration(stdin);
  }
});

function consoleInteration(stdin) {

  //RESULT FROM AJAX POST
  result = "This is the output from the shell";
  terminal.append('<br><div class="static">' + result + '</div><br>');
  terminal.append('<div class="static"><span class="fa fa-arrow-right console-arrow"></span> ~ </div>');
  terminal.append('<div class="stdin" id="stdin" contenteditable="true"></div>');


}
```

```css
.terminal {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  height: 650px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.terminal div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.terminal .static {
  color: #5ed7ff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.console-arrow {
  color: #bde371;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="terminal" class="terminal">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What you need

First, [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/): this allow you to change the `contenteditable` attribute (true/false).

Secondly [.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/): focus the desired element (just get the last `.stdin` with [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/)).

---

#### Handling the cursor

In your div (the one that works like an input), you will make the text color as transparent with `color: transparent`, this way you will hide the cursor.
But you need the text to show, so you will add `text-shadow` to help: `text-shadow: 0 0 0 black`.
To create the cursor, you will need one `<div>` after the other with editable content.

With everything set, you make use of [.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) with [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to change the visibility and, at every change, [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) the last cursor `<div>`.

---

```js
var terminal = $('#terminal');
window.setInterval(function () {
      if ($('#cursor').css('visibility') === 'visible') {
          $('#cursor').css({
              visibility: 'hidden'
          });
      } else {
          $('#cursor').css({
              visibility: 'visible'
          });
      }
  }, 500);

$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var stdin = $('.stdin').last().text();
    console.log(stdin);
    consoleInteration(stdin);
  }
});

function consoleInteration(stdin) {

  $("#cursor").remove();
  $(".stdin").last().attr("contenteditable", "false");

  //RESULT FROM AJAX POST
  result = "This is the output from the shell";
  terminal.append('<br><div class="static">' + result + '</div><br>');
  terminal.append('<div class="static"><span class="fa fa-arrow-right console-arrow"></span> ~ </div>');
  terminal.append('<div class="stdin" id="stdin" contenteditable="true"></div>');
  terminal.append('<div id="cursor"></div>');

  $(".stdin").last().focus();
}
```

```css
.terminal {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  height: 650px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
  white-space: -pre-wrap;
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.terminal div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.terminal .static {
  color: #5ed7ff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.console-arrow {
  color: #bde371;
}

.stdin{
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 white;
}

#cursor {
    top: 10px;
    width: 7px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: #5ed7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="terminal" class="terminal">
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't see yours, just posted to help the answer. Still editing it.
Thanks for the upvote! :D

Comment: Oh no, I didn't mean that you copied my answer. I just meant we posted the same solution almost at the same time.

Comment: Oh, I was just saying.
It's funny that somebody thinks the way you think. :P

Answer (score 2):

You can disable edition by doing :

```
$('.stdin').last().removeAttr("contenteditable")
```

Then append the next line :

```
terminal.append('<div class="stdin" id="stdin" contenteditable="true"></div>')
```

Then select the last (newly added) line and set focus on it :

```
$('.stdin').last().focus()
```